# Transferring ASCII (sub)set to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, ascii

I am trying to transfer a subset of ASCII characters to a table but I keep getting an error saying I am duplicating values in SSMS.

This is my code for the table:

```
create table xyz(
  aChar char not null,
  primary key(aChar)
);
```

and this to populate the table:

```
declare @xChars int = 250
declare @iterations int = 0
while @iterations < @xChars
begin
insert into xyz values (char(@iterations))
set @iterations += 1
end
```

Hopefully one of you can help me out here.

Comment: Before you start the loop, truncate the table:  `truncate table xyz`.

Comment: ASCII has only 128 codepoints, so in fact you aren't working within ASCII. The CHAR (and ASCII) functions don't use ASCII either. You should understand the character set and encoding you need and choose a collation—and also text types—carefully. NCHAR and NVARCHAR are often better choices for the text types than CHAR and VARCHAR. (But twice the bytes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a case-insensitive collation.  `'a'` and `'A'` are the same thing.  So, use a case sensitive collation:

```
create table xyz (
  aChar char collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS not null,
  primary key(aChar)
);
```

You can do this with a single statement:

```
with nums as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n + 1 < 250
     )
insert into xyz (aChar)
    select char(nums.n)
    from nums
options (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75713/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

You can also do this using a computed column:

```
create table xyz(
  aChar_num smallint not null,
  aChar as (char(aChar_num)),
  primary key(aChar_num)
);

with nums as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from nums
      where n + 1 < 250
     )
insert into xyz (aChar_num)
    select nums.n
    from nums
    option (maxrecursion 0);
```

As shown in [this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b75a6/1) SQL Fiddle.

Comment: That clarified a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Character data in SQL Server is stored with a collation.  A collation defines the sort order and equality comparison for text.  The default collation is case-insensitive, so the character 'a' and the character 'A' compare as equal.  You have a unique index on aChar, so you can't store 'a' and 'A' in the column.  There also may by whitespace or non-printable characters that will compare equal.

You want to declare that column with a binary collation so that the characters compare by their code point, not by a linguistic collation.  eg

```
drop table if exists xyz
create table xyz(
  aChar char  collate Latin1_General_BIN2 not null,
  primary key(aChar)
);
go
declare @xChars int = 250
declare @iterations int = 0
while @iterations < @xChars
begin
insert into xyz values (char(@iterations))
set @iterations += 1
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the help as well.